# How to hide identical entries in extjs grid column?

Tags: extjs, datagrid, duplicates, extjs4.2

I am using extjs 4.2 and have following question:

> Is it somehow possible to hide duplicate entries in an extjs grid column?

I don't want to lose the data in the store. The data model shouldn't be manipulated. Only the view!
E.g. There is 1 column with following entries

Column
   A
   A
   B
   B
   C
   D
   E
   E

In the end it should be like

Column
A

B

C
D
E

Is there a possibility to solve this in extjs?

Thanks for your hints in advance.

Comment: You cant try [renderer](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer). But you have to control in your store if the column data is a repeated value and control which value you want to show and which one you don't.

Comment: Thanks! That is working for me. Couldn't believe I didn't try it before asking for it in this thread... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hello and thank you qmat.

My solution looks like that:

```
renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
  var count = 0;
  var val = '';

  //Searching for duplicates, which are already in the column and count them
  store.each(function(record) {
    if (record.get('ColName') === value && lastOne === value ) {
      count+=1;
    } 
  });   

  //Process and render data like you wish.
  if(count > 1){
    val = '';
  } else {
    val = 'editedValue';
  }
  count = 0; // reset counter
  lastOne = value; // last added data in column without duplicates.

  return val;
}
```

If you have an easier solution, please let me know.

Greetings and thanks again. :-)